# ¿Qué hace la siguiente expresión regular en PHP?

Tags: php, regex, php7

Estoy usando una librería de email para PHP de hace 14 años y me reemplaza los textos que tengan tilde o ñ por strings vacíos.

Después de horas de pruebas, he localizado la línea responsable de ello.

```
//TODO using /e (equivalent to eval()) is probably not a good idea
$encoded = preg_replace('/([\000-\011\013\014\016-\037\075\077\137\177-\377])/e',
                        "'='.sprintf('%02X', ord(stripslashes('\\1')))", $encoded);
```

Honestamente, no sé exactamente que hace eso, pero creo que detecta los tildes. El resultado de pasar un texto con tilde o ñ por esa línea es un string vacío.

¿Cómo puedo actualizar esa línea a una que sea compatible con PHP 7.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, esa expresión regular lo que hace es detectar los caracteres como a Ñ, caracteres con tilde, interrogación "?", guion bajo "_" e igualdad "=" :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer esta pasándole específicamente su valor en ASCII para detectar caracteres puntuales.

Puedes validarla con mas detalle en [esta web](https://regexr.com/).

Por otro lado, la expresiones regulares son un estándar, sea cual sea el lenguaje en el que programes la expresión siempre será la misma, lo que cambia es la manera de aplicarla. Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: El /e final de la expresión me hace saltar un warning en PHP 7. Ya no se usa más.

Comment: Entonces edita tu pregunta y coloca el warning para poder identificar mejor la causa de tu problema.